# Getting information on why I was suspended after asking a question

Tags: support, help-center, account-suspension

I've been suspended on Super User after asking a question and also answering one.
I'm wondering whether there is another way to find out why I was suspended and why my question and answers were deleted.

I heard you get the reason for a suspension in your inbox; however, the "message" that is in my inbox simply is titled goodbye. When I attempt to access this message, it is a "Page not found" page.
Even when trying to access it through other means, like directly from the message centre, it just brings me to the "page not found" page.

I've also submitted an appeal about a month or so ago to find out why I was suspended and to try and appeal. Of course, this process would take a long period of time, so I have been fairly patient.
Although, I am asking whether there is another way to go around this process/issue.

Comment: Since this is a request for support, the procedure was followed, and having [determined that there was an error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370233/getting-information-on-why-i-was-suspended-after-asking-a-question#comment1235636_370236), it isn't helpful to mark a separate post as a duplicate of another.

Comment: Should this be moved to Meta Super User since it is about a suspension on that specific site?

Comment: I guess. At the point this was asked - OP couldn't ask there. I wonder if there's value keeping it here for other users who might have gotten nuked tho.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The 'goodbye' moderator message was/is generally used when we're deleting an account for spam or nonsense.

A quick look at your posts suggests you linked to a known printer support scam site
(if you can recall - [it's this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1674800/how-to-connect-printer-to-a-laptop-tried-all-methods-from-google-searches/1674802#1674802), and the other answers were just on the wrong side of "is this a human being or is this a bot?" - since they've gotten a little smarter and post a few vague answers alongside spam in some cases.

I'd urge a lot more caution in linking sites off the Internet - we go through nuking about half a dozen of these a day - and these sites are suspicious and actively malicious in many cases.

Fundamentally - in trying to be helpful, **you linked to a scammer** and it looked indistinguishable from a spam bot.

We deal with so many of these that they tend to be quickly flagged and handled. It's a *great* idea to check your sources and ensure they're legitimate. Sites that hide their phone numbers at the bottom, or give you useful tips to fix a problem and go "Or you can use our easy instamagical tool" tend to be non legitimate.

Generally we often pair up those deletions with one year suspensions to discourage use of spammers or trolls reusing the same credentials - which I see is in place now, but I'd rather not remove the suspension without finding the full circumstances of events.

After an internal review by the SU moderator team we'll be lifting the suspension - since it's kind of clear this is an honest, if unfortunate mistake. Do be more careful in the future over what you link, and do be more skeptical over your sources.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if the message when deleting an account was more informative.

Comment: But did the OP first receive a message warning them that their sources and links were suspicious looking? Is the line between being suspicious-looking and being a spammer fuzzy? I don't know, I'm just asking.

Comment: Oh - we get so many damned printer spammers that... they tend to get nuked on sight. I generally (personally) don't even bother mod messaging or suspending them.  I think this is one of the few times there was a false positive I'm aware of.

Comment: @Mari-LouA We generally don't want to give second chance for spammers. So instead of giving them any hints to be able to promote their products on here, we usually just nuke the accounts (and additionally suspend them without useful info).

Comment: I hate those trash websites but I'm not active on SU, so I didn't know the situation was that bad. Wow!

Comment: You don't know the situation is that bad cause ... those posts don't last long

Comment: @41686d6564 If you want to see the quantity & quality of the spam that gets dumped on the network, visit the [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) chatroom & their [website](https://charcoal-se.org/about)

Comment: @PM2Ring Speaking of the Charcoal HQ chatroom, it also appears that I am banned from those chatrooms due to being banned on a parent website. Would this also be a result of the suspension from SU or something separate?

Comment: @Riotline, that's probably the case. Journeyman Geek should be able to give you a definitive answer (and get it fixed).

Comment: hm. That didn't sync for some reason. Sorted out

Comment: Is there a message template for "this account is being deleted because we think it is being used to spam"? If not shouldn't there be a one-click suspend/delete that generates a boilerplate message? It won't make a difference to the spambots, but it would help people in this situation. I realize that it is often difficult to distinguish people innocently linking to spam/scams from actual scammers, but it is a mistake in my opinion to send mod messages with no content, if for no other reason than there should be a record of why the account was deleted.

Answer (score 9):

You should:

- Contact Stack Exchange by using the [contact link](https://superuser.com/contact) at the bottom of any page - there's even a reason specifically for profile suspensions.
- Ping a moderator in chat.

Your account is suspended until a year from now. Simply getting suspended "after asking a question and also answering one" isn't possible. You must have done something much worse.

As mentioned in @JourneymanGeek's answer, you posted some links... Which where likely to be spam.

But now the moderator team has lifted your suspension. Feel free to post on Super User now.

Comment: There's always a chance OP using shared computer, or their IP address is somehow shared, by someone already suspended, hence for all the mods know, it's a user trying to bypass suspension. So while "must have done something much worse" still makes the most sense, we can't know for sure that's really the OP doing.